# How to break HTML page dynamically on certain condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, semantic-ui

I have a HTML Page which has FORM fields. I would like to break HTML Page based on certain condition (I am considering this condition as $CheckForm). I tried with css element page-break-after/before but that doesn't work for me since I have a table where dynamic rows will be added into HTML form by clicking on Add Row button.

```
$(function() {
            console.log("Custom Javascript Loading");
            //console.log($("#row30").closest("div").attr("id"));
            var m_names = new Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", 
            "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", 
            "Oct", "Nov", "Dec");

            var dateToday = new Date();
            var curr_date = dateToday.getDate();
            var curr_month = dateToday.getMonth();
            var curr_year = dateToday.getFullYear();
            var today = curr_date + " " + m_names[curr_month] + " " + curr_year;

            $('#projectNo').focus();

            var $checkForm = 31;

            if($checkForm < 30){
                $('#estimatedDate').val(today);
                $('#promiseDate1').val(today);  
            }
            if($checkForm > 30){
                $(".req_field").css("cssText", "color: black !important;");
                $(':input').removeAttr('placeholder');
                for(var $i=1;$i<=25;$i++){
                    if(($('input:radio[name=supplier'+$i+']:checked').val()) && ($('.member'+$i+'').css('display')=="table-row")){
                        $('#supplierBlock'.concat($i)).hide();
                        $('#supplierText'.concat($i)).removeClass('supplierDisplay');
                        $('#supplierText'.concat($i)).val($('input:radio[name=supplier'+$i+']:checked').val());
                    }
                }
                $('#add_row').remove();
                $('#add_row').height(0);
                $('#delete_row').remove();
                $('#delete_row').height(0);
                $('#imgDateSet').remove();
            }
            var writeT = "";
            if($checkForm > 30){
                for(var $i=1;$i<=36;$i++){
                    var temp = '#row'+$i;
                    var tempDisplay = $(temp).css('display');

                    //$('#projectNo').val($('#row11').offset().top.toFixed(2)+','+$('#row30').height());
                    if (tempDisplay != "none"){
                        console.log(temp+':'+$(temp).attr('id'));
                        console.log($(temp).offset().top.toFixed(2));
                        var rowHeight = $(temp).height();
                        var rowStart = $(temp).offset().top.toFixed(2);
                    }

                    writeT = writeT + ', '+temp +':'+$(temp).offset().top.toFixed(2);

                    var checkPage = Math.floor(rowStart / 1080 );
                    if(rowStart > 1000){
                        rowStart = rowStart - (1080 * checkPage);
                    }
                    //console.log('I val:'+$i+'->'+rowStart);
                    if ((rowStart + rowHeight) > 963){ //963    
                        var $m1 = $('<div class="ui page grid" style="page-break-before:auto !important;"></div>').appendTo('form');
                        var $m2 = $('<div class="wide column"></div>').appendTo($m1);
                        var $m3 = $('<div class="ui divider hidden"></div>').appendTo($m2);
                        var $m4 = $('<div class="ui segment form"></div>').appendTo($m2);

                        $($m2).append('<footer><p style="font-size:11px"><a href="#"><span style="float:left;">COMPANY CONFIDENTIAL AND PROPRIETARY</span><span style="float:right;">Copyright &copy <span>'+dateToday.getFullYear()+'</span> Fisher BioServices, Inc. All Right Reserved</span></a></p></footer>');
                        $($m2).prepend('<h1></h1><table class="ui celled table"><tr><td><img src=""/></td><td>SPECIFICATION NUMBER:<span style="float:right;font-weight:bold; color:blue">FBS-FRM-0186</td></tr><tr><td style="text-align:center;" colspan="2"><span style="font-weight:bold; font-size:15px;">REQUEST FOR VALIDATION SERVICES</span></td></tr></table>');

                        if (($i >= 1 && $i <=4) || ($i >= 31 && $i <=36)){
                            $(temp).nextAll().andSelf().appendTo($m4);
                        }

                        if(($i >= 5 && $i <=30) && (tempDisplay != "none")){
                            var $t1 = $('<table id="requirementDetails'+$i+'" name="requirementDetails'+$i+'" class="ui celled" style="table-layout:auto"></table>');
                            var $t2 = $('<thead></thead>').appendTo($t1);
                            var $t3 = $('<tr style="height:40px !important;"><th class="th1">Number</th><th class="th2">Required Component</th><th class="th2">Description / Specific Manufacturer requirement</th><th class="th2">Quantity per BR / Kit #</th><th class="th2">FBS / Client Supplied</th><th class="req_field th2">*PR #</th><th class="req_field th2">*CMP or CTS #</th><th class="req_field th2">*Promise date from Client / FBS Purchasing</th><th class="th2">MSDS provided (drug product only)</th></tr>').appendTo($t2);
                            var $t3 = $('<tbody></tbody>').appendTo($t1);
                            $(temp).nextAll().andSelf().appendTo($t3);

                            var $m5 = $('<div id="furtherInfo'+$i+'"></div>').appendTo($m4);
                            var $m6 = $($t1).appendTo($m5);
                            $(temp).closest('div').nextAll().andSelf().appendTo($m4);
                        }
                    }
                    //$('#comments').val(rowStart);
                }
            }
     });
```

I tried to break the HTML form using offset() and top() and break the page if any of the row crosses the page limit (I have set page limit to 963) but somewhere I am missing something.

Here is my Jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/0t16c0p3/3/

Could anyone help me how can I achieve this?

Comment: by the page break what you mean what you want to achieve

Comment: what does breaking HTML page means?

Comment: @AatifBandey Divide the HTML into equal parts with the Commond Header and Footer which will be more precised rather than long html page

Comment: @AkashAgrawal  Divide the HTML into equal parts with the Commond Header and Footer which will be more precised rather than long html page

Comment: Actually JavaScript works okay but not completely so I would like to get input from you guys.